# Variable cambia de valor solo en la condicion de bucle while

Tags: javascript, while

estoy comenzando en esto de la programacion, y al ver un ejemplo de un curso que estoy haciendo, noto que en un bucle while, una variable con valor false al pasar por la condicion pasa como true, pero al entrar al bucle vuelve a false.

```javascript
let terminado = false;
let contador = 1;

while (!terminado) {
    terminado = !confirm(`[${contador++}] Continuar el bucle?`);
}
```

La variable "terminado" se declara como false, e ingresa al bucle como true ya que en la condicion se modifica su valor con el operador NOT. Pero, si coloco un console.log en la condicion para verificar el valor de la variable, veo que el codigo me trae true... Y si coloco un console.log en el bloque de codigo, me trae false...

```javascript
let terminado = false;
let contador = 1;

while (console.log(!terminado)) { // -> true
    terminado = !confirm(`[${contador++}] Continuar el bucle?`);
}
```

```javascript
let terminado = false;
let contador = 1;

while (!terminado) {
    console.log(terminado); // -> false 
    terminado = !confirm(`[${contador++}] Continuar el bucle?`); 
    console.log(terminado); 
}
```

Mi duda es, porque ocurre esto? La variable fuera del bucle es false, al pasar por la condicion es true, y al entrar al bucle es false nuevamente.

Les agradeceria si me pueden aclarar este comportamiento, tal vez sea normal o yo no este entendiendo algo.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en realidad es un error de interpretación. La expresión

```
!terminado
```

no cambia el valor de la variable, sólo el valor devuelto. Te lo explico con un ejemplo, supongamos el código

```js
let terminado = true;
let noterminado = !terminado;
console.log(terminado);
console.log(noterminado);
```

Una vez ejecutado, el resultado será:
true
false

Esto es así porque el valor de *terminado* no se modifica. Por eso, la sentencia

```
while (!terminado)
```

ha de leerse como MIENTRAS NO TERMINADO, pero sin modificar la variable.

Por otro lado, la construcción que has hecho

```
while (console.log(!terminado))
```

es incorrecta, porque el while aquí lo que estará comprobando es lo que devuelve el método *log*, que no es lo que se pretende. En realidad esta sentencia se leería como MIENTRAS LO DEVUELTO POR console.log(...) SEA CIERTO

Espero haber sabido explicarme y no haberte liado más

Comment: Perfecto @Pedro González, muy clara tu respuesta. Crei que el operador logico NOT modificaba el valor de la variable. Muchas gracias.